# ARIMA - determine if model is stationary and if invertible

Tags: arima, stationarity

My understanding is that for the MA(3) model (for example) 
$$y_t = \beta_0 + \epsilon_t + \beta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} + \beta_2  \epsilon_{t-2} + \beta_3 \epsilon_{t-3} \\
y_t = 2 + \epsilon_t - .5 \epsilon_{t-1} + .1 \epsilon_{t-2} + .1 \epsilon_{t-3}$$ 
to determine if it is stationary you:

- $\sum_{i, i<>0} {|\beta_i|}$ (in this case we have .7)
- if that sum is >= 1 you have a non-stationary (divergent) model
- if the sum < 1 you have a stationary (convergent) model. This also makes it invertible.

**Question 1:** Please confirm if you exclude $\beta_0$ from the sum.

**Question 2:** Does it make sense to ask if the model is invertible when it has AR and MA such as in: $$y_t = 2 + .5 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t - .7 \epsilon_{t-1}$$? I.e. do we talk about invertibility only when we want to go from a purely MA model to purely AR? I understand that all things being roughly equal (think of having an AR(1) and MA(1) model) you would pretty much always want to go with the AR model instead of MA. So is invertibility only applicable when you would want to go from MA to AR?

**Question 3:** How about the stationarity of the model in question 2?

- $\sum_{i, i<>0} {|\alpha_i|} = .5$
- $\sum_{i, i<>0} {|\beta_i|} = .7$
- In this case is the model stationary or not (I ask because individually the MA and AR are stationary but what about the model as a whole)?
- Finally, what if:

  - $\sum_{i, i<>0} {|\alpha_i|} = 1.5$
  - $\sum_{i, i<>0} {|\beta_i|} = .7$
  - In this case by the sum of the alphas alone the model would not be stationary. Would this automatically make the whole model non-stationary?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You inverted the formulas of MA(1) and AR(1).

Comment: Why do you have all the seemingly-unnecessary summation terms in your questions when you only have one element in each sum?

Comment: I updated the question to include more terms. Is it safe to say that invertibility applies when you want to go from a purely MA model to purely AR? If so I'm clear about the rule. If you can apply invertibility to an ARMA model, does it usually mean that you want to invert the MA part to AR so that you end up with an AR only model? My understanding is that AR models have several benefits over MA so usually you want to invert from MA to AR and not the other way around.